# Get Google Colab autocomplete in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ide, google-colaboratory

I recently started using Google Colab and absolutely love the autocomplete UI. I usually code in Jupyter Notebook and hence am used to an autocomplete which only returns the single methods and takes a second or two to load. Google Colab on the other hand is instant, returns the method and also tells you the expected arguments and a description of what a method does. I love it, it reminds me of my old days in eclipse.

Therefore I wanted to ask if there is a module/plugin for Jupyter Notebook to have this UI. Otherwise, is there a different IDE like Jupyter (with these code snippets) with the advanced autocomplete functions? Possibly open source. Thanks.

Comment: Colab appears to be using the Monaco editor from vs code. Code actually now has its own notebook editor and it's pretty good, with the autocomplete and lots of other features.

Comment: Thank you, I will look into it even though I like to avoid Microsoft programs. However it is open source. Do you know if you can set the Notebook style UI as a default?

Comment: There is a version of vscodium without MS branding on it ;). Your entire theme is applied to the notebook ui

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the **Hinterland**, it's an extension that enable code autocompletion menu for every keypress in a code cell, instead of only calling it with tab.

You can lean how to enable an extension in [here](https://github.com/ipython-contrib/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions#3-enablingdisabling-extensions), and read more about **Hinterland** in [here](https://jupyter-contrib-nbextensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/nbextensions/hinterland/README.html).

I hope it helped you